# Way to determine when a modular form divides another?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Given modular forms $f, g$ for $SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ of weights $l, k$ resp. where $l < k$, is there a way to see if $f \mid g$? That is, is there a way to see if $g = fh$ for some modular form $h$ of weight $k-l$?

At least in terms of $q$-expansions over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, there are some examples: $E_{p-1} \mid f$ for any reduced form $f$ since $E_{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. So perhaps the above question can be more easily attacked in the mod $p$ setting? Would there be a way to extend the $E_{p-1}$ case to the mod $p^{m}$ setting?

I'm not sure how one would approach answering this question other than literally dividing $q$-expansions and writing the result as a linear combination of basis elements from the appropriate space of forms. If we only look at Eisenstein series, then some results on Bernoulli numbers could be useful.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's what you want, but I think you just need to check whether at each zero $z$ of $f$ (in the fundamental domain and infinity), the order of vanishing of $g$ is at least that of $f$. Then $g/f$ will be holomorphic and a modular form.

Comment: @user14411 Right! This works for any particular case. I'm more so wondering if there's an algorithm to do this in general (which is probably too much to ask for).

Comment: I'm skeptical of your claim that $E_{p-1}\mid f$. $E_4^3 - E_6^2$ is a weight $12$ cusp form, but I don't know what to think about $\frac{E_4^3}{E_6} - E_6$.

Comment: If you're interested in eigenforms, then Duke [has a paper](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~wdduke/preprints/when.pdf) that discusses when the product of two eigenforms is an eigenform (answer: there are only finitely many examples, all forced by dimension)

Comment: @Mathmo123 This is a cool paper, thanks. My claim should be rewritten as $\tilde{E}_{p-1} \mid \tilde{f}$ to signify reduction of $q$-expansions. However, it isn't as insightful as I let out; it's just saying that 1 divides anything in the ring.